# Laravel 4 - how to return all validation error messages for all fields as a JSON structure?

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-4

I'm upgrading from Laravel 3 to Laravel 4. My app has some AJAX-only forms that are rendered client-side (i.e. there are no server-side views). Therefore, instead of passing validation errors to views with the **withErrors()** method, I've been returning the validation error objects to the client as JSON structures.

In Laravel 3, I had this:

```
$validation = Validator::make(Input::all(), $rules);
if($validation->fails())
{
  return json_encode($validation->errors);
}
//else handle task
```

But in Laravel 4, the error messages are protected:

```
$validation = Validator::make(Input::all(), $rules);
if($validation->fails())
{
  var_dump($validation->messages());
  return json_encode($validation->messages());
}
//else handle task
```

**var_dump($validation->messages())** returns:

```
object(Illuminate\Support\MessageBag)[333]
  protected 'messages' => 
    array (size=1)
      'delete_confirm_password' => 
        array (size=1)
          0 => string 'The delete confirm password field is required.' (length=46)
  protected 'format' => string ':message' (length=8)
```

**json_encode($validation->messages)** returns

```
{}
```

**Question:** how do I return all the validation error messages for all fields as a JSON structure in Laravel 4?

Comment: Have you tried typecasting as an array before encoding? Not sure if it'll work but worth a go: `$messages = (array)$validation->messages; return json_encode($messages);`

Comment: @FDL - thanks. Your comment lead me to a working answer (the messageBag class has a **toArray()** method.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

I discovered it was possible to use the **toArray()** method:

```
return json_encode($validation->messages()->toArray());
```

Answer (score 58):

Simply use `toJson()` method.

```
return $validator->messages()->toJson();
```

Answer (score 16):

Here is another way that let u add HTTP code to the response:

```
return Response::json($validation->messages(), 500);
```

Comment: superb! HTTP Response Code should be a must for AJAX validation ie

Comment: This should probably use `400 request cannot be fulfilled due to bad syntax` instead of `500 server error`. Since this is likely a client rather than server error.

Answer (score 3):

I think that this is the Laravel way to get the error messages. There are special methods to get them. So here how I do this stuff:

```
return Response::json($validator->errors()->getMessages(), 400);
```

This produces output in the following format:

```
{
"field_name": [
     "Error message"
     ]
}
```